# Bold a field label, resize fields in Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: javascript, crm, field, microsoft-dynamics

I don't think this is possible using the Xrm. framework but I have to ask.
We have labels next to our fields and one we want to bold is the Sub Total. I can't see any way to do this without going through document.getElementById and setting it that way somehow, but from what I read this is completely unsupported. As well, we'd like to set set some fields to take up more exact amount of space than just 25%, 33%, 50%, 66%, 75% and 100%, because some text entry fields are just way too long, like 40 characters wide for something that only needs to be 7.

Comment: What do you need to do exactly ? Can you share some of your code or use jsfiddle to show your problem ?

Comment: Say there is a text box called "new_pricingsubtotal" with the label "Sub Total:" displayed. I need to make the words "Sub Total:" next to the input box bolded so that it sticks out from the page. I was able to create a Web Resource that occupies one line and does what I want but then the problem is that it doesn't lay out like I want. http://imgur.com/a/zq2Kd top image is how it is now. I'd like the Sub Total: to be bolded. Bottom image shows using a Web Resource I can accomplish what I want but it takes up too much space and pushes the total over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a supported way to do that, but to set bold take a look:

```js
document.getElementById("new_name").style.fontWeight="bold";
```

The space of controls is more complicate, but you can do the same with bold but affect the size of field.

Comment: I have created the following code:

`function BoldLabel(LabelName) {
  document.getElementbyId(LabelName).style.fontWeight="bold";
}
`

and then I call it with the parameter 'new_pricingsubtotal' but it keeps saying the object doesn't support that method.

Comment: You are right, it's just to be generic. Which rollup of CRM you have?

Comment: We are on the latest version UR12

Comment: Seems to work if I hard specify the control "new_pricingtotal_c" in the getelementbyid but not if I pass it as a paramater... doy? i must be doing something trivially wrong.

Comment: pay attention to getElement*B*yId a typo issue i think.

Comment: JavaScript casing is killing me... Thanks Pedro!!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with this code below and the parameter `'MYCustomField_c'`:

```
function BoldLabel(LabelName) 
{ 
   document.getElementById(LabelName).style.fontWeight="bold";
}
```